# Как сохранить состояние при повороте экрана?

Tags: java, android

Простой вопрос, но мне как новичку разобраться сложно.
Есть текст `TextView` вложенный в `ScrollView`. Как при повороте экрана сохранить то место, где остановился читать? По учебнику нужно использовать: `onRestoreInstanceState` и `onSaveInstanceState`. Но я не пойму, что нужно прописывать в этих методах.

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".old_unused.ActivityBox_1">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/RelativeBox">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Ranishni"
        android:text="@string/This_1"
        style="@style/Size.text">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ошибки

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getTop()' on a null object reference
    at ua.pl.prayerbook.ActivityBox.onSaveInstanceState(ActivityBox.java:93)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте `SaveInstanceState` для сохранения состояния.

```
ScrollView scroll

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Тут сохраняем в outState позицию скролла
    outState.putInt("scroll",scroll.getTop());
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // А тут восстанавливаем позицию скролла
    scroll.setTop(savedInstanceState.getInt("scroll",0);
}
```

Comment: Вы написали то, что автору и так известно - использовать onSaveInstanceState и onRestoreInstanceState. Вопрос как раз в том и заключается - как сохранять позицию скролла.

Comment: @Эникейщик, точно... Невнимательно прочитал вопрос. Щас поправлю ответ...

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Но есть еще один момент, при повороте экрана вываливается приложение. Добавил код ошибки. Там что-то на null нужно проверять, наверное.

Comment: @Олександр Переменной `ScrollView scroll` присвойте значение.